# Clean URLs on multisite; Clean URL test fails but unable to enable it

Tags: 7, .htaccess

Clean URL test fails but unable to enable it. Here is my configuration files. I am able to access the page via `example.com/admin/config/search/clean-urls` as well as `example.com/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls`

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are unable to enable it because the test fails ;-) I think, the rewrite module isn't enabled for your APACHE server. You can try executing `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: Wait, how is it that test fails if you can, in fact, access page using clean URLs?  Never heard it to be possible

Comment: @AjitS its enabled see http://i.stack.imgur.com/mMbz0.png

Comment: @Mołot see this http://i.stack.imgur.com/JxC4Q.png i cant enable it. Form never get saved.

Comment: @Mołot, oh its fine. Any suggestion or thoughts ?

Comment: If you can tell why exactly you think you need QSA, I may be able to tell you how to avoid that need. Probably in separate question.

Comment: I had this problem once too. I could visit both the q url and the clean url, but by default my site keeped serving the q urls. I can't find the article where I got the solution, but (from memory) it involved visiting the example.com/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls to  url twice or thrice to disable clean-urls and enable it again. Then it worked. Don't try to alter it at the clean url. (this was with a default drupal htaccess though).

Comment: @Marcel okay i will try that.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in your [`[QSA]` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> To combine a new query string with an old one, use the [QSA] flag.

You don't want to do that. Drupal works fine with just:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

If you will combine original query string with new one, then the test in [`system_clean_url_settings()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_clean_url_settings/5) have to fail, as it is:

```
if (strpos(request_uri(), '?q=') !== FALSE) {
```

If you are attaching original query string to new one, you are also adding that `?q=`, and this makes Drupal think you are still using non-clean method.

Comment: Note: I know I oversimplified how mod_rewrite and QSA works. It is the detail level that lets me get my stuff done, but if you are pro Apache admin and you are giggling now, feel free to post more detailed explanation, or edit my post with details.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, its still the same. Enable clean URLs form not getting saved. Clean URL test fails but url works without `?q=`

Comment: but in my subdomain its not working without `?q=`

Comment: I never had problems with subdomains, without any QSA flag and with clean urls. Always using Drupal's standard `.htaccess`. As far as I know, http://um.warszawa.pl and all it's subdomains, like http://zielona.um.warszawa.pl are still built just that way, and there are no problems. So it's some deeper problem with your subdomains, I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you help me further on this? Do you need any more info?

Comment: @NikhilM I'll get back to you when I'll figure what I might ask. The team that was working on the sites mentioned above no longer exists as a team, but I'll try to ask others, we still know each other on private and business level.

Comment: Any luck yet? I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have .htaccess in your drupal root directory, it is hidden by default so to check if you have .htaccess in file simply ls -a in your drupal root directory.

Comment: `.htaccess` is there and its working.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified it in your question, but is the subdomain located in the same directory /var/www?
As far as I know rewrite rules are per directory.
If this is the casa as it looks to me, you have to another rewrite rule.

This works as charm for me:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com mydomain.com
    UseCanonicalName On
    ErrorLog logs/mydomain.com.err
    CustomLog logs/mydomain.com common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com mydomain.com
    UseCanonicalName On
    ErrorLog logs/mydomain.com.err
    CustomLog logs/mydomain.com common
</VirtualHost>


<Directory /var/www/mydomain.com/>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

If you have the subdomain located in another path then you mast add a second rewrite rule.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/second_domain.mydomain.com/
    ServerName second_domain.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.second_domain.mydomain.com
    UseCanonicalName On
    ErrorLog logs/second_domain.mydomain.com.err
    CustomLog logs/second_domain.mydomain.com common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/second_domain.mydomain.com/
    ServerName second_domain.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.second_domain.mydomain.com
    UseCanonicalName On
    ErrorLog logs/second_domain.mydomain.com.err
    CustomLog logs/second_domain.mydomain.com common
</VirtualHost>


<Directory /var/www/second_domain.mydomain.com/>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

Also, remember to restart the httpd server: **service httpd restart**

Change the paths and the domain names accordingly. Are you using the root **/var/www**? For your site, it would be better if you used a subdirectory to store your sites as in this example. Furthermore, if you continue using the path **/var/www** check that there is not another rewrite rule included by default in your configuration file. In vi: when not editing, press slash and add te text: www, and press enter, // enter to search again; and check there is not any other rewrite rule for this path...

Another problem may be with the caches, check **Admin/Configuration/Performance** and click on **Clear all caches**.

I hope that this may be helpful...

Comment: Its a typical subdomain in `/var/www/sites` 1 site named dev and 1 is live i mapped the live www site to a subfolder in `/sites` like `/sites/www.site.com`. Am i clear ?

Comment: Have you tried any of this?

Comment: As i told you my folders are not different as you specified in the answer.

Comment: I see, loosing my time here...

Answer (score 0):

The clean URLs test does a local HTTP request

```
$request = drupal_http_request($GLOBALS['base_url'] . '/admin/config/search/clean-urls/check');
```

I think in your case, the `drupal_http_request` is failing so Drupal marks the clean url test as failed.

More info: [`system_clean_url_settings`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.admin.inc/function/system_clean_url_settings/7)

Comment: But i am able to browse the site without the `?q=` thats what driving me crazy.

Comment: Yes, it's only the test that fails, clean urls still work, silly I know. You'll need to figure out why the local drupal_http_request is failing in your environment there

Comment: Any clue on that? I have no idea on that.